# How to Save data to influxDB using a spark streaming job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, influxdb

I have tried library **pygmalios/reactiveinflux-spark** but its dependency is prone to error with our set of libraries and also have tried **com.paulgoldbaum/scala-influxdb-client** which is giving runtime error while reading file in cluster.
Is there any reliable library to address the needed solution

Comment: Could you shed a little light on "giving runtime error while reading file in cluster"? Why is it reading file in cluster? I have had success writing to Influx using com.paulgoldbaum/scala-influxdb-client. Hence curious

Comment: Hi Mathews,
Thanks for your interest.!!
It meant when I am reading stream data from kafka using spark streaming job, its giving me java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture..!!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.newAtomicIntegerFieldUpdater(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater;

Comment: It would be great if you can help me with set of dependencies you have used to accomplish it

Comment: These are my dependencies..
libraryDependencies +="org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0" % "provided",
libraryDependencies +="org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0" % "provided",
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.1.0" % "provided",
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.1.0",
libraryDependencies += "com.paulgoldbaum" %% "scala-influxdb-client" % "0.5.2",
dependencyOverrides += "org.asynchttpclient" % "async-http-client" % "2.0.12"

Comment: Nothing much different there.
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0" % Provided,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.3.0" % Provided,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.3.0",
"org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "1.0.0",
 "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.11.362",
 "com.paulgoldbaum" %% "scala-influxdb-client" % "0.6.1"
Do you mind sharing your code?